# how to update customer email from another form in prestashop

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.7

I am validating mobile number and retrieving customers email address and allowing customers to change the emaill address in that form  and now I need  to update the email address  how to do this from my custom controller, ie  how to call  the Customer class and update  my email address in prestashop

```php
elseif (Tools::isSubmit('update_email')) {
    $otp_mobile_num = trim(Tools::getValue('otp_mobile_num'));
    $update_email = Tools::getValue('update_email_address');
    $old_email = Tools::getValue('old_email_address');  
    //d($otp_mobile_num);
    if($old_email!= $update_email) {
        //d($update_email);
        // Checked the email address is already in use, in case he changed his email address
        if (Validate::isEmail($update_email) && !empty($update_email)) {
            if (Customer::customerExists($update_email)) {
                $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('An account using this email address :('.$update_email.') has already been registered.', false);
            }
        }
    } else {
         $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('You must change the email address!');
    }
}
```

Below is my seperate form :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try updating directly the Context Customer:

```php
elseif (Tools::isSubmit('update_email')) {
    $otp_mobile_num = trim(Tools::getValue('otp_mobile_num'));
    $update_email = Tools::getValue('update_email_address');
    $old_email = Tools::getValue('old_email_address');  
    //d($otp_mobile_num);
    if($old_email!= $update_email){
        //d($update_email);
        // Checked the email address is already in use, in case he changed his email address
        if (Validate::isEmail($update_email) && !empty($update_email)) {
            if (Customer::customerExists($update_email)) {
                $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('An account using this email address :('.$update_email.') has already been registered.', false);
            } elseif(Context::getContext()->customer->id == null) {
                $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('You must be logged in');
            } else {
                Context::getContext()->customer->email = $update_email
                if(Context::getContext()->customer->save()) {
                    // Customer updated correctly
                } else {
                    $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('An error occured');
                }
            }
        }
    }else{
         $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('You must change the email address!');
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want the customer to be loged in  , i want the mobile validation option if he get the otp and  verifys that , then he will have an option to change email address

Comment: Then please update your question and explain carefully your process as it is currently unclear.